# wso2am 2.1.0 on oracle - sqlexception missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2AM-2.1.0-update12 (carbon-apomgt tag v6.2.108) normally works well with mysql. We intend to switch the underlying database to Oracle DB (11g as far I know), looks simple.

Wen creating an API the apim throws an SQLException

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

we traced the exception to

```
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO:7652
```

executing following query:

```
  SELECT 
   A.SCOPE_ID, A.NAME, A.DISPLAY_NAME,
   A.DESCRIPTION, C.SCOPE_BINDING 
   FROM  
   ((IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE AS A  INNER JOIN  AM_API_SCOPES AS B ON A.SCOPE_ID = B.SCOPE_ID)
   INNER JOIN  IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_BINDING AS C ON B.SCOPE_ID = C.SCOPE_ID )
   WHERE B.API_ID = 1;
```

Running this query itself against the APIM database indeed reproduces the exception, so the code hasn't been properly tested. For some customizations we rather try to fix the code if possible than migrate to a newer version (where we have no ensurance the issue is fixed or our customizations will work)

I suspect the query as been not tested as at all and correct query may look like

```
  SELECT 
   A.SCOPE_ID, A.NAME, A.DISPLAY_NAME,
   A.DESCRIPTION,   C.SCOPE_BINDING 
   FROM  
     IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE  A  INNER JOIN  AM_API_SCOPES B ON A.SCOPE_ID = B.SCOPE_ID
   INNER JOIN  IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_BINDING  C ON B.SCOPE_ID = C.SCOPE_ID 
   WHERE B.API_ID = 1;
```

I'd like to validate and correct me if the query is syntactically and semantically not equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following?

```
SELECT A.SCOPE_ID, A.NAME, A.DISPLAY_NAME, A.DESCRIPTION, C.SCOPE_BINDING FROM ((IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE A  INNER JOIN  AM_API_SCOPES B ON A.SCOPE_ID = B.SCOPE_ID) INNER JOIN  IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_BINDING C ON B.SCOPE_ID = C.SCOPE_ID ) WHERE B.API_ID = ?
```

You can find this corrected query in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/6.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/impl/dao/constants/SQLConstants.java#L2068